# Can I password protect excel work book with XLRD?

Tags: python, excel, password-protection, xlrd

I want to deliver an EXCEL application and I'm finding out whether I can password protect a whole work book with Python and XLRD libray? Does any one around know how I can do this with the XLRD on python?

Answer (score 1):

As the [README](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd/blob/master/README.html) says, in the "Outside the current scope" section:

> **Unlikely to be done**:
>
> - Handling password-protected (encrypted) files.

On top of that, note that `xlrd` is only for reading data from Excel files, not generating or modifying them (`xlwt` does that). So, even if it were possible, `xlrd` wouldn't be the way to do it.